# Appendix in an article

Tags: appendix

I am trying to add an appendix to an article but I keep getting errors. This is my code:

```
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix}
\section{Velocity} \label{ap:velocity}
```

In Overleaf, the article is compiled and an "appendix" appears but instead of being numerated with letters it is done with numbers, as if it was a section, and it also shows that there is an error with the command. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try this `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix}
\section{Velocity} \label{ap:velocity}
\end{document}`  In which I just put packages after `documentclass` and also `\end{document}`

Comment: The [toc] option should automatically add the appendix to the TOC, as would \addappheadtotoc.  \addcontentsline will add the section counter, which you don't want.